# PHP variable has two values

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I've got a project that involves getting flight information from a database.

I want the results to look like:

---

01 Nov 2017 - Eastern Airways 7601

Departing from Southampton, Eastleigh (SOU) at 0840

---

However my code seems to bring up the below with a mysterious live of nonsense as per below

---

01 Nov 2017 - Eastern Airways 7601

Departing from , () at 084001 Nov 2017 - 7601 //**this line I don't want**

Departing from Southampton, Eastleigh (SOU) at 0840

---

From what I can see in my code below ,I've narrowed it down to the $row variable, if I do

```
print_r($row);
```

Then I get the following result

Array ( [0] => 266 [1] => CX [2] => Cathay Pacific )

Array ( [0] => 5021 [1] => Manchester [2] => MAN [3] => Manchester [4] => United Kingdom [5] => GB [6] => 493 )

So it looks like there's two arrays under the $row variable, one from each query - I'm not sure why this has happened, or how to get rid of it!

```
$link = mysqli_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx' );

foreach ($flights as $b) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM  `airlines` WHERE  `iatacode` =  '$airline' LIMIT 0 , 30;"; 
$query .= "SELECT * FROM  `airports` WHERE  `Airport Code` =  '$depdest' LIMIT 0 , 30;"; 
/* Execute queries */

if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {
do {
/* store first result set */
if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))


/* print results */    
{
        $date=date_create($depdate);
echo "<b>" . date_format($date,"d M Y"). " - ". $row['airlinename']." ".$flightno. "</b><br/>";


echo "Departing from " .$row['City Name'].", ".$row['Airport Name']." (".$row['Airport Code'].") at " . $deptime;

}
mysqli_free_result($result);
}   
} while (mysqli_next_result($link));
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I thought they were different, is this not the case? One is from the "Airlines' table, and the other is from the 'Airports table'

Comment: Your print_r() output is not correct.  If it was your output would be nothing but empty strings.  Don't use mysqli_muliti_query.  Your code is going to be a confusing mess.  Break it up into 2 seperate queries. Also bind variables -- don't use interpolated strings.

Comment: Oh, I actually read them as the same, my bad. I deleted my comment.

Comment: Can you share the table structure? And by the way, columns shouldn't be named with spaces in them.